# How to add several input fields per entry - admin form in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, database, admin, collection, adminform

I want to be able to edit one poll and it's answers in one admin form, and have one input field per answer. I already have my collections ready, how can I create a working admin form ?

```
POLLS TABLE                   ANSWERS TABLE
PollId | PollText             AnswerId | PollId | AnswerText
 1     | 'Question1'           1       |  1     |  'Answer 1'
 2     | 'Question2'           2       |  1     |  'Answer 2'       
                               3       |  2     |  'Answer a'
                               4       |  2     |  'Answer b'
```